# Sed / awk / perl text editing on n lines after match

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I'm strugling with this.
I'm trying to edit the next 6 lines after a match, by adding text before each lines, and double quotes before and after the existing number on each lines.

What my file look like:

```
"data": [
    4,
    15,
    43,
    10,
    60,
    45
```

What I'm trying to get as output:

```
"data": [
    "stuff": "4",
    "stuff": "15",
    "stuff": "20",
    "stuff": "13",
    "stuff": "4",
    "stuff": "25",
```

I've trying this:

```
sed '/"data"/{N;N;N;N;N;s/\([0-9][0-9]\)/"stuff": "\1"/}'
```

But it seems to only edit second line after match.
I'm not an expert so I can't figure this out.
Any idea / help would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`, or have you considered a tool that actually understands JSON structure such as `jq`?

Comment: Note that in JSON, you also need to change `[` to `{`.

Comment: I can use any tool, including those who needs some kind of install, as long as it can run on a debian 9.
But what I'm trying to achieve with this regexp editing is to convert that json to SQL statement in order to insert it into a database.
I found several ways to do that, but each needs flat json; and this is why I'm trying to insert statements before each line that doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

**Code fix:**

```
sed '/"data"/{N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/"stuff": "\1"/g}'
```

**Test run:**

```
$ sed '/"data"/{N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/"stuff": "\1"/g}' input.txt
"data": [
    "stuff": "4",
    "stuff": "15",
    "stuff": "43",
    "stuff": "10",
    "stuff": "60",
    "stuff": "45"
```

**Explanation:**

You are skipping the first line because you are searching for a double-digit number, and `4` only has one digit. If you want all occurrences to be substituted, you should add the `g` (global) modifier. Lastly, in order to include the last line, add one more `N;`

---

**Alternative:** Here's a slightly more robust and general Perl:

```
perl -lape 's/([0-9]+)/"stuff": $1/ if /"data"/../]/'
```

---

**Alternative:** You could edit your input file to make it "flat", and then convert it in one of several ways.

---

**Better alternative:** Use `jq` or some other specialised tool/library to convert JSON files. Do not treat them as text files.